# Finding and sketching CDF for $Y=g(X)$ random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

The question asks me to find an expression for $f_Y(y)$ if $Y = g(X)$ is defined as in (1). And also sketching $F_Y (y)$ if $F_X(x)$ is given by Fig. 1

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/910Mc.png)
[image]

I got the derivative of $g(x)$. And I used the formula of $\sum_{i=0}^n f_X(x_i)/g'(x_i)$ .
But I couldnt see how to find $f_X(x)$. And sketching was whole another story. I couldnt even imagine. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

For $y<0$ you have
$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X+c\leq y, X\leq-c)=P(X\leq y-c)=F_X(y-c).$$
For $y>0$ you have
$$F_Y(y)=F_X(y+c)$$
by a similar calculation. Lastly,
$$P(Y=0)=P(X=-c)+P(-c<X\leq c)=P(X=-c)+F_X(c)-F_X(-c)=F_X(c)-F_X(-c),$$
where $P(X=-c)=0$ comes from the observation that $F_X$ does not jump as $-c$.

So what does the graph of $F_Y$ look like? On $(-\infty,0)$ you see the graph of $F_X$ on the interval $(-\infty,-c)$. At $0$ there is a jump of size $F_X(c)-F_X(-c)$. On $(0,\infty)$ you see the graph of $F_X$ on the interval $(c,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Osman ağabey I think we don't need to re-sketch the $F_Y(y)$, it's just shifted version of $F_X(x)$. I found the expressions like these: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96nOc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).